# AWS credentials for httpd / apache different from those set for ec2-user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

**How can get httpd / apache to use a specific access_key, secret_key and region?**

I've used `aws configure` to set up the default credentials for an EC2 instance, with the default ec2-user. I can successfully retrieve these using `aws configure list`, and I can successfully make calls to things like `aws s3api` when logged in via ssh as ec2-user.

I'm running apache as httpd on the instance in question. When I try to make a call from the web application, for example using php `$output = shell_exec('aws s3api Example-Commands --output text 2>&1');` I receive an error, 403 Forbidden. If I run `$output = shell_exec('aws configure list --output text 2>&1');` then I see that the access_key and secret_key are not those which I supplied using `aws configure`.  If I instead run these commands from SSH when logged in as ec2-user they work.

httpd seems to be running as user "apache" when using

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-26-0-172 ~]$ ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
root      7425  0.0  0.3 4***76 2***6 ?        Ss   Apr15   1:39 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9074  0.3  1.0 5***16 8***8 ?        Sl   22:45   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9075  0.0  0.2 4***20 1***0 ?        Sl   22:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9081  0.2  0.8 5***04 6***6 ?        Sl   22:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

`nano ~/.aws/credentials` shows the credentials I had previously entered.

I wish to have httpd use the credentials that I previously supplied to aws configure, but am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Any reason why you are hard codding the credentials on your instance? Its not a good practice.

Comment: But anyway, a possible reason is that when you login using ssh, your `ec2-user` credentials are used. When you run the commands from `httpd`, httpd's credentials are used.

Comment: Honestly - because the AWS manuals that show and tell how to do it are the most common thing to come up when you're looking for how to interact with other aws services. 

The IAM account that owns the credentials has fairly limited privileges.

Comment: Yep - so how do I give ```httpd``` the right credentials? That's the part where I'm lost.

Comment: Not sure. One way would be to set some environment variables with the credentials for apache to use.

Comment: So that worked. Thanks! What is a better way of doing it? Attaching an IAM role to the instance somehow?

Comment: I added answer with the link on the use of the EC2 instance roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments the solution was to use `environment variables` so that Apache can access the credentials.

However, it should be noted that hard codding credentials on an instance is **not a good practice**. The recommended way is to [Attach an IAM role to your existing Amazon EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/):

> IAM roles enable your applications running on EC2 to use temporary security credentials that AWS creates, distributes, and rotates automatically. Using temporary credentials reduces the risk of long-term key compromise..